# How to work around error "Delete Prevented by referential constraint" in DB2?

Tags: db2

So the problem I have is in my task provided to us by the Professor we are to

1. create tables
2. insert records to each table.
3. update and delete (minimum of 1 record) from each table

using a DB2 Script that is following the old standard where COLLECTIONS are created instead of SCHEMAS

steps 1 and 2 are done. the updates are done. my deletes are giving me a hard time. an example would be this.

```
CREATE TABLE UMALIK8.CAMPUS (
CAMPUS_ID VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
CAMPUS_NAME VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
MANAGER_NUM VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT UMALIK8.CAMPUS_PK PRIMARY KEY (CAMPUS_ID),
CONSTRAINT UMALIK8.CAMPUS_FK FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER_NUM)
REFERENCES UMALIK8.MANAGER(MANAGER_NUM)
ON DELETE CASCADE);

INSERT INTO UMALIK8.CAMPUS (CAMPUS_ID, CAMPUS_NAME, MANAGER_NUM)
    VALUES ('King', 'King Campus', 'M021386');

DELETE FROM UMALIK8.CAMPUS
    WHERE CAMPUS_ID = 'King';
```

so when I try to delete it, it says delete prevented by referential constraint "roomassign_fk" which doesn't make sense to me because the roomassign table is like 3 or 4 tables AFTER the campus table, the campus is the parent table, and the manager number is from the manager table and the parent table for manager table is Employee table....all throughout the delete script im getting referential errors and I don't know why. Even in my adult table but my adult table has no foreign keys, its only got a primary key on its own, and its got a bunch of child tables....

Now the order of my script is

Tables,
Inserts,
Updates,
Deletes
all separated from each other in one long script

any idea how to fix this? what am i doing wrong?

your help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to exist on this table `UMALIK8.CAMPUS` a trigger which is inserting registries in a table that has an FK to it?

Comment: I'm not quite following what you mean. I have 4 INSERTs into the campus table, I'm trying to delete the record that contains King, the other inserts does not have the same campus_ID, would the others interfere?
Should I just post my entire script?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I think I figured it out, it seems the order of my delete functions are interfering and causing a script error---it seems because of some tables that are FK to multiple tables I need to delete in a different order---at least that's what it seems like.

Comment: What I mean with a trigger is that if your table has a `after insert trigger` that would mean something like this: you run the insert command on CAMPUS, after the insert happens the DB2 will call the trigger and insert in a ROOM (i think that is the name of other table) one registrie which will be linked (by fk) to the one you just inserted on CAMPUS, then if you try to delete the registrie on CAMPUS the `referential constraint "roomassign_fk"` will happen because you have a child registry that is linked to the one in CAMPUS. Hope you can understand now. And glad that you have figured it out.

Comment: If you post the entire script it will be easier to find out the problem and explain it on details to you.

Comment: @JorgeCampos you were right, can you post that as an answer so i can select it, the trigger was exactly my issue and after looking at what you said reorganizing my delete script in the correct order of triggers fixed my entire problem and i was able to submit my assignment before deadline and do my exam correctly! so thanks so much man super appreciate it!

Comment: Done it. Glad to help you to understand and solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed on the comments with the OP turns out that the issue is about a trigger on the table `CAMPUS`. As the OP asked I'm putting this as an answer.

Is it possible to exist on this table UMALIK8.CAMPUS a trigger which is inserting registries in a table that has an FK to it?

What I mean with a trigger is that if your table has an **after insert trigger** that would mean something like this: you run the insert command on `CAMPUS`, after the insert happens the `DB2` will call the trigger and insert in a ROOM (i think that is the name of other table given the FK name) one registry which will be linked (by FK) to the one you just inserted on `CAMPUS`, then if you try to delete the registry on `CAMPUS` the referential constraint `"roomassign_fk"` will happen because you have a child registry that is linked to the one in `CAMPUS`